# How to generate .a to .so

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I own a number of .a files and would like to generate .so using ndk-build.

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH  := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := nonfree
LOCAL_MODULE += opencv_java3

LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=              \
    libopencv_aruco.a           \
    libopencv_bgsegm.a                  \
    libopencv_bioinspired.a     \
    libopencv_calib3d.a     \
    libopencv_ccalib.a     \
    libopencv_core.a     \
    libopencv_datasets.a     \
    libopencv_dnn.a     \
    libopencv_dpm.a     \
    libopencv_face.a     \
    libopencv_features2d.a     \
    libopencv_flann.a     \
    libopencv_fuzzy.a     \
    libopencv_highgui.a    \
    libopencv_imgcodecs.a    \
    libopencv_imgproc.a    \
    libopencv_line_descriptor.a    \
    libopencv_ml.a    \
    libopencv_objdetect.a    \
    libopencv_optflow.a    \
    libopencv_photo.a    \
    libopencv_plot.a    \
    libopencv_reg.a    \
    libopencv_rgbd.a    \
    libopencv_saliency.a    \
    libopencv_shape.a    \
    libopencv_stereo.a    \
    libopencv_stitching.a    \
    libopencv_structured_light.a    \
    libopencv_superres.a    \
    libopencv_surface_matching.a    \
    libopencv_text.a    \
    libopencv_tracking.a    \
    libopencv_ts.a    \
    libopencv_video.a    \
    libopencv_videoio.a    \
    libopencv_videostab.a   \
    libopencv_xfeatures2d.a   \
    libopencv_ximgproc.a   \
    libopencv_xobjdetect.a   \
    libopencv_xphoto.a

LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

To use the NDK-build used these [steps](http://kn-gloryo.github.io/Build_NDK_AndroidStudio_detail/).

When trying to generate .so this returning me this error:

> C:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\ndk-build.cmd clean Android NDK:
>   LOCAL_MODULE definition in jni/Android.mk must not contain space
>   C:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/build-shared-library.mk:23:
>   *** Android NDK: Please correct error. Aborting    .  Stop.
>
> Process finished with exit code 2

Comment: Why are you using `PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY` if you're trying to build a shared library?

Comment: Oops, my error ... I changed to SHARED but still have questions about how to generate a lib opencv 3.1 with contrib to use the SURF. I followed a step by step where github with cmak commands just generating this huge list ".a" and would like to join in a single ".so". I do not know if there is an easier and correct to generate this lib with contrib SURF.

Answer (score 1):

`LOCAL_MODULE` specifies the name of the final .so file built.
ndk-build is giving an error since a [space is introduced in the name when you concatenate the two strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Appending.html) `nonfree` and `opencv_java3`:

```
LOCAL_MODULE := nonfree
LOCAL_MODULE += opencv_java3
```

If you would like a concatenated name I would suggest doing this manually:

```
LOCAL_MODULE := nonfree_opencv_java3
```

You will then need to specify this name when you load the .so file through JNI.

Comment: Thanks for reply... I got this error: C:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\ndk-build.cmd clean
C:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:28: *** missing separator.  Stop.
Android NDK: ERROR:jni/Android.mk:nonfree_opencv_java3: The LOCAL_SRC_FILES for a prebuilt library should only contain one item    

Process finished with exit code 2